# Compartilhamento de link no Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Estou fazendo um sistema para o meu curso e encontrei um grande problema na parte onde devo compartilhar o link do site diretamente no Facebook.

Tenho o botão em meu site que faz abrir direto a janela de publicação do Facebook, estou mandando este link para ser compartilhado:

```
http://localhost/BAC....pag=lerMais.php?&codigo=3
```

Porém, quando o link vai para o Facebook, clico nele para abri-lo, mas o link vai apenas:

```
http://localhost/BAC...pag=lerMais.php
```

Ou seja, ele apaga o `&codigo=3`. Como consertar esse erro?

```
function mensagem (codigoConteudo) {
    var link = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://localhost/BACKUPS_TCC/09/Sistema3009/areaAdm.php?pag=lerMais.php&codigo="+codigoConteudo;
    window.open(link, 'facebook_share', 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no',"gl");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenho a impressão de que seja porque o valor passado (que é uma URL inteira) não está devidamente codificado para URL. Tente:

```
var link = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + encodeURIComponent("http://localhost/BACKUPS_TCC/09/Sistema3009/areaAdm.php?pag=lerMais.php"+codigoConteudo);
```

Comment: FUncionou cara, muito obrigado!!! valeu mesmo :)

Comment: @MatheusLuz por favor, se a resposta funcionou, marque ela como correta, leia por favor [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635)